# Ant: javac task: path versus pathelement

Tags: ant, path, javac, src, pathelement

I would like to know the difference between the
following javac Ant tasks.

```
<!-- Task 1 -->
<javac destdir="${build}" classpath="classes.jar" debug="on">
  <src path="${src}"/>
  <src>
    <pathelement path="${src2}"/>
    <pathelement path="${src3}"/>
  </src>
</javac>

<!-- Task 2 -->
<javac destdir="${build}" classpath="classes.jar" debug="on">
  <src path="${src}"/>
  <src path="${src2}"/>
  <src path="${src3}"/>
</javac>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, every path is being added to the source paths.